# Include statement not working

Tags: c++, arduino

I am creating my own library for the Arduino and I have the following code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Servo.h>

class ServoMotorController {
    public:
        ServoMotorController(int servoPin, int motorPin, int angle);
        void setAngle(int angle);
        void setSpeed(int speed);
    private:
        Servo servo;

        int servoPin;
        int servoAngle;
        int motorPin;
        int motorSpeed;
};
```

I am getting the error that `Servo` does not name a type; however if I do

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <ServoMotorController.h>
```

in my actual Arduino code then I do not get the error. **Why is the include statement not working in my C++ lib?**

***Here is more info:***

File Hierarchy:

```
Arduino
     libraries
          MyServo
               ServoMotorController .h
               ServoMotorController .cpp
          Servo
               SoftwareServo.h
               SoftwareServo.cpp
     Servo_Program
          Servo_Program.ino
```

ServoMotorController.h is the file shown above.

When I use the arduino IDE to include the servo library it does

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include <ServoMotorController.h>
```

And there are no problems, but if I do not include the  in the arduino file and only in the .h&.cpp files it says that Servo does not name a type.

Comment: Circular include dependency/missing forward declaration problems probably. Hard to tell from what you're showing.

Comment: Maybe you don't tell your compiler where to find the `Servo` library.

Comment: If I do #include <Servo.h> in the arduino .ino file it works perfectly.  Just not in my library

Answer (score 0):

Too long for the comment box…

Do you use guards for your include files?

```
#ifndef SERVO_H
#define SERVO_H
 . . . . . 
#endif



#ifndef SERVOMOTORCONTROLLER_H
#define SERVOMOTORCONTROLLER_H
 . . . . . 
#endif
```

Comment: See my post for more info (under more info)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of this helps but to include a header file you created you might want to use the quotes instead of angle brackets"

#include "ServoMotorController.h"